# XML style not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get this error when I visit http://www.scrum.com/rss/rugby/story/feeds/0.rss:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>...</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an RSS feed, it is supposed to be XML.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

Comment: I found this link useful... please see and let me know http://www.androidpit.com/java-guide-2-program-your-own-rss-reader. i just want to know how to use that code in telerik tool.